# How To cast a child class to base class when base class is generic in c#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have these classes:

```
public class BaseGame<T> where T : BaseQuestion
{
    //some fileds and methods
}

public class BaseQuestion 
{
    //some fileds and methods
}

public class Question : BaseQuestion
{
    //some fileds and methods
}

public class SampleGame : BaseGame<Question>
{
    //some fileds and methods
}
```

Whenever i want to cast BaseGame to SampleGame i get Error.

```
void SetValue(BaseGame<BaseQuestion> _game)
{
    SampleGame = (SampleGame) _game;
}
```

Cannot implicitly convert type BaseGame to SampleGame.
How To Fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `_game` parameter an instance of `SampleGame`? How did you create the paremeter you pass to the `SetValue` method?

Comment: I have many Games , one of them is SampleGame . but in this particular method(SetValue) i know that _game is an instance of SampleGame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public interface IBaseGame<out T> where T : BaseQuestion
{
}

public class BaseGame<T> : IBaseGame<T>
    where T : BaseQuestion
{
}

public class BaseQuestion 
{
}

public class Question : BaseQuestion
{
}

public class SampleGame : BaseGame<Question>
{
}
```

And then your method:

```
void SetValue(IBaseGame<BaseQuestion> _game)
{
    var SampleGame = (SampleGame) _game;
}
```

**Why was your code broken?**

You cannot do the cast because `BaseGame` was not covariant. This means that the compile *cannot* gaurantee that the cast is safe. Take for example, the following example:

```
public class BaseGame<T> where T : BaseQuestion
{
    private List<T> Questions { get; set; }
    public void AddQuestion(T question) { Questions.Add(question); }
}

var game = new BaseGame<Question> { Questions = new List<Question> };
game.AddQuestion(new Question());
```

Okay, so now your game has a list of `Question`, with one question in it. Now let's cast it:

```
public class BrokenQuestion : BaseQuestion
{
} 

public class BrokenGame : BaseGame<BrokenQuestion>
{
}

var brokenGame = (BrokenGame)game;
brokenGame.Add(new BrokenQuestion());`
```

Oops! We just added a `BrokenQuestion` to a `List<Question>`. No good.

Defining the template argument as `out T` instead of `T` means we're making a contract that we will not *accept* sub classes of `T`, but we can *return* them. This means that it's now *illegal* to expose `AddQuestion(T question)`. Now, the compiler can be sure that there will never be a `BrokenQuestion` added to `List<Question>`.

For more information, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)